# Fluent Style interaction with JSON objects

Tags: json

I have a sample JSON object

```
{
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

I am looking for some fluent syntax to filter or manipulate JSON array.Something like

```
.Where(firstname == 'Peter')
```

Could you please suggest me some js libraries to manipulate JSON objects using fluent style function.

Comment: Something like [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer the [linq.js library](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/).It is a handy library to meet your requirement.
As Blender pointed out ,you can even try [jLINQ](http://jlinq.codeplex.com/)